# Azure: Why downtime during SSL certificate update for API gateway (http) and Listeners

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I have a mobile app and because my SSL certificate was expiring; on Microsoft azure portal I updated my SSL certificate for the api gateway (http) and apim (listeners). I noticed there was a downtime of around 2-3 min. 
Please help what could be the reason. Please suggest if there is any way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the API Management service offering then you need to ensure you're not on the Developer SKU.

The certificate can take up to 15 minutes to apply on all SKUs, but if you're on a Basic or higher SKU, these provide an SLA and there should be no downtime.  Any downtime experienced resultant from application of a cert should be taken up with Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I am new in this area. Is there any way to check what is my SKU? developer sku or basic sku. I have access to azure portal so just wondering i can check it from there or not?

Comment: In "configuration" tab on the azure portal, i can see the Tier is "WAF" and "SKU" size is "Large". Shall i contact to microsoft?

Comment: That would be Application Gateway as opposed to API Management.  Regardless, although it takes some time to apply, there should be no downtime.  Yes, I would raise a ticket with MS about this issue.